# Hide and Show HUD Window - Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, hud

I have a HUD window that has some labels on it, and I want this to show when the user presses a button. I know this is simple, but I can't get it to show again unless I restart my program.

Sincerely,

Kevin

Comment: I think you should show the code you're using to show it, and the code (if any) you're using to hide it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To hide `hudWindow`:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [hudWindow orderOut:nil]; // to hide it
}
```

Then on button press:

```
- (IBAction)showWindow:(id)sender {
    [hudWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil]; // to show it
}
```

Comment: You don't need to hide the window programmatically on launch, you should just uncheck the "Visible at launch" checkbox in Interface Builder.

Comment: for this should I make an outlet? and the should the type be NSPanel?

Answer (score 8):

In IB, go to the window's attributes inspector and make sure that "Released when closed" isn't checked.

Comment: I needed this to fix my HUD window, if I closed the window and then showed it again, I got a window where no clicks would register.  When I unticked "Released when closed" my window was interactive again and back to normal, so thanks!